# WHAT IS DIFFERENCE BETWEEN get_user_model() ,settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and USER in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

WHAT IS DIFFERENCE BETWEEN get_user_model() ,settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL and User in django ?

Answer (score 9):

They have different use cases.

You need to use `get_user_model()` or `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` for referencing the User model **when dealing with "unknown" User model**.
E.g. you are writing a module that will be used in different applications, which may use a custom User model.

If you are writing a simple app, that will no be reused, if you prefer, you can use the `User` model, that you can import from your model if you customized it, or from the django itself. E.g. `from myapp.models import MyUserModel`

In particularly, you have to use:

- `get_user_model()` when you need to import the User model to query it. E.g.

```
User = get_user_model()
User.objects.filter(...)
```

- `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` when you need to referencing User model in `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField` or `OneToOneField`. E.g.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

If you try to user `get_user_model()` when creating ForeignKey`,`ManyToManyField`or`OneToOneField` you may have circular import issues.

You also have to set `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `settings.py` if you want to provide a custom implementation for the user model. E.g. `AUTH_USER_MODEL='myapp.MyUserModel`

Comment: bro i can user User model in Model relationship like:--

class MyModel(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)

Answer (score 1):

**get_user_model()**

> Instead of referring to User directly, you should reference the user
>   model using django.contrib.auth.get_user_model(). This method will
>   return the currently active user model – the custom user model if one
>   is specified, or User otherwise.
>   [Read more](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model)

**settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL**

If you create a custom `User` model then you have to add this model to your settings

**User**

If you don't use custom `User` model, then you don't need to add it in `settings.py` file. Just import the model whenever you need.